# What is the difference between a subgroup and semigroup?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

In my text it says $\{e^{i\theta}:\theta\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a subgroup but it did not clarify the subgroup of which group.

Furthermore I remember this entire set as being a semigroup, is there a difference between a subgroup and semigroup?

Comment: How has this question become a hot question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A subgroup is a subset of a group that is itself closed under the group operation.

A semigroup is a set equipped with an operation that is merely associative, different from a group in that we assume the binary operation of a group is associative and invertible, i.e. each element has an inverse with respect to the operation.

Comment: Oh right right I remember that the matrix exponential $e^{D}$ $D$ some matrix is a semigroup. But it did not occur to me that $e^{D}$ was not invertible. Can you confirm whether the matrix exponential is invertible or not?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, I haven't worked with matrix exponentials. Can someone else answer this?

Comment: The exponential of a matrix is of course invertible, as $\mathrm e^A\cdot\mathrm e^{-A}=I$. More than that, the expoential of a matrix is a surjective mapping from  $M_n(K)$ onto $\operatorname{GL}_n(K)$, but it's not a group homomorphism, as $\;\mathrm e^A\cdot\mathrm e^{B}=\mathrm e^{A+B}$ only if $AB=BA$ ($K=\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$).

Comment: @bernard thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ equiped with multiplication. So it's also a group (a subgroup is a group).
A semigroup is just a set with an associative operation. So every group is also a semigroup, but the converse is false.